# How to get parent's text using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I have situation where I want to get a parent `<p>` tag's text. For example:

```
<p>
  <a name="TOPIC"></a>
  <b><font color="#800000" size="4" face="Arial">Exapmles</font></b>
</p>
```

This is working fine for this example:

```
test = Nokogiri::HTML("row['test']"])
raw_attributes = test.root.css("p a").inject({}) do |accumulator, element| 
  accumulator[element.attr("name")] = (element.parent.text).strip
  accumulator
end
```

But it's not working for the following example:

```
<p>
  <font>
    <a name="TOPIC"></a>
    <b><font color="#800000" size="4" face="Arial">Exapmles</font></b>
  </font>
</p>
```

How can I do this using Nokogiri? I want the solution which works for both of the above two conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts doc.at_xpath("//p[//a[@name='TOPIC']]").inner_text.strip
#=> "Exapmles"
```

Decoded, this says:

- `//p` — find a `p` element anywhere in the document

  - `[…]` — that matches this condition
  - `//a` — it has an `a` element as a descendant

    - `[@name='TOPIC']` — with a `name` attribute whose value is `TOPIC`.